# Unable to get property 'selectedIndex' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting the following error in IE 11 when running the following javascript code which allows me to select items from a pop up list box and save them. This works in IE 9 without issues.

```
function passMultiList(src, selected)
{
    dst = parent.frames['downright'].document.getElementById('chosen');
    var src_array = src.split("_");
    for(g=0; g<src_array.length; g++){
        src_array[g] = document.getElementById(src_array[g]);
        if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
    }
    for(i=0; i<src_array[0].options.length; i++){
        if(src_array[0].options[i].selected==true){
            var text = src_array[0].options[i].text;
            var value = src_array[0].options[i].value;
            if(src_array.length==1){
                flag = 0;
                for(k=0; k<dst.options.length; k++)
                {
                    if(dst.options[k].value == value)
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    dst.options[dst.options.length]=new Option(text, value);
                    if(selected == 1)
                    {
                        dst.options[dst.options.length-1].selected=true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                passList(src_array, 0, text, value, selected);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

It is raising an error on the following line

```
if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
```

Unable to get property 'selectedIndex' of undefined or null reference

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: Please find the (complete) relevant code below, this includes the changes you guided me to make:

```
        function passMultiList(src, selected)
{
    dst = parent.frames['downright'].document.getElementById('chosen');
    var src_array = src.split("_");
    for(g=0; g<src_array.length; g++){
        src_array[g] = document.getElementById(src_array[g]);
        if(src_array[g] != undefined) {
            if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
        }
    }
    var src_pushed = [];
if(src_array[g] != undefined) {
    src_pushed.push(src_array[g]);
            if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
}
    if(src_array[0] != undefined) {
      for(i=0; i<src_pushed[0].options.length; i++){
        if(src_pushed[0].options[i].selected==true){
            var text = src_pushed[0].options[i].text;
            var value = src_pushed[0].options[i].value;
            if(src_pushed.length==1){
                flag = 0;
                for(k=0; k<dst.options.length; k++)
                {
                    if(dst.options[k].value == value)
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    dst.options[dst.options.length]=new Option(text, value);
                    if(selected == 1)
                    {
                        dst.options[dst.options.length-1].selected=true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                passList(src_array, 0, text, value, selected);
            }
        }
      } 
   }
} 


        function passList(src_array, current, text, value, selected){
            var y = current +1;
            for(j=0; j<src_array[y].options.length; j++){
                if(src_array[y].options[j].selected ==true){
                    var atext = text + " and " + src_array[y].options[j].text;
                    var avalue = value + "_" + src_array[y].options[j].value;
                    if(y == src_array.length-1){
                            flag = 0;
                            for(k=0; k<dst.options.length; k++)
                            {
                                if(dst.options[k].value == avalue)
                                {
                                    flag=1;
                                }
                            }
                            if(flag==0)
                            {
                                dst.options[dst.options.length]=new Option(atext, avalue);
                                if(selected == 1)
                                {
                                    dst.options[dst.options.length-1].selected=true;
                                }

                            }
                    }else{
                        passList(src_array, y, atext, avalue, selected);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*
        function passMultiList(src1, src2, selected)
        {
            dst = parent.frames['downright'].document.getElementById('chosen');

            if(src1.selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src1.name); return;}
            if(src2.selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src2.name); return;}
            for(i=0; i<src1.options.length; i++){

                if(src1.options[i].selected==true){
                    for(j=0; j<src2.options.length; j++){
                        if(src2.options[j].selected==true){
                            var text = src1.options[i].text + "-" + src2.options[j].text;
                            var value = src1.options[i].value + "_" + src2.options[j].value;
                            flag = 0;
                            for(k=0; k<dst.options.length; k++)
                            {
                                if(dst.options[k].value == value)
                                {
                                    flag=1;
                                }
                            }
                            if(flag==0)
                            {
                                dst.options[dst.options.length]=new Option(text, value);
                                if(selected == 1)
                                {
                                    dst.options[dst.options.length-1].selected=true;
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        */

        function passSingleList(srcName, selected)
        {
            src = document.getElementById('single');
            dst = parent.frames['downright'].document.getElementById('chosen');
            if(src.selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + srcName); return;}
            for(j=0; j<src.options.length; j++)
            {
                if(src.options[j].selected==true)
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    for(k=0; k<dst.options.length; k++)
                    {
                        if(dst.options[k].value == src.options[j].value)
                        {
                            flag=1;
                            if(selected == 1)
                            {
                                dst.options[k].selected=true;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(selected == 1)
                            {
                                dst.options[k].selected=false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if(flag==0)
                    {
                        dst.options[dst.options.length]=new Option(src.options[j].text, src.options[j].value);
                        if(selected == 1)
                        {
                            dst.options[dst.options.length-1].selected=true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: what is the content of your src_array[g] when t he error appears? I would suggest to try for(var g=0; g<src_array.length; g++) ... (var is missing)

Comment: I think the xsl part is also needed (unlike the not used part of the code) - sadly i'm not really familar with xsl, however I m not sure whether the function call at the input is working correctly. Can you try to alert the variable at the beginning of your function? Is it working correctly? try alert(src); at the first line of your passMultiList function - please tell us what the result is

Answer (score 0):

Your source seems to contain parts, which are not selectable in the line:

```
src_array[g] = document.getElementById(src_array[g]);
```

to get rid of the problem you could insert the follwing:

```
src_array[g] = document.getElementById(src_array[g]);

if(src_array[g] != undefined) {
    if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
}
```

This will fix your problem **IF** your problem isn't a wrong src entry.

ofcourse, you would then also need to change your further code - for example you shouldnt go for src_array[0] directly - without checking whether it is undefined or not

update: since i don't know the purpose of your code, i ll try to complete it as far as i can - IMPORTANT: this won't fix the fact that your first element is undefined. Something in your src is wrong OR the element does not exists even though it should.

```
function passMultiList(src, selected)
{
    dst = parent.frames['downright'].document.getElementById('chosen');
    var src_array = src.split("_");

    for(g=0; g<src_array.length; g++){
        src_array[g] = document.getElementById(src_array[g]);
        if(src_array[g] != undefined) {
            if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
        }
    }
    if(src_array[0] != undefined) {
      for(i=0; i<src_array[0].options.length; i++){
        if(src_array[0].options[i].selected==true){
            var text = src_array[0].options[i].text;
            var value = src_array[0].options[i].value;
            if(src_array.length==1){
                flag = 0;
                for(k=0; k<dst.options.length; k++)
                {
                    if(dst.options[k].value == value)
                    {
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                    dst.options[dst.options.length]=new Option(text, value);
                    if(selected == 1)
                    {
                        dst.options[dst.options.length-1].selected=true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                passList(src_array, 0, text, value, selected);
            }
        }
      } 
   }
}
```

You could however try to fix this by pushing the correct entries into a new array:

```
var src_pushed = [];
```

...

```
if(src_array[g] != undefined) {
    src_pushed.push(src_array[g]);
            if(src_array[g].selectedIndex < 0){ alert("Please select a " + src_array[g].name); return;}
}
```

...

```
 for(i=0; i<src_pushed[0].options.length; i++){
```

...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74841/discussion-on-answer-by-frank-provost-unable-to-get-property-selectedindex-of).

Answer (score 0):

I finally worked out what was causing the issue:

IE 11 is expecting an id to be passed through whilst older versions of IE didn't require this.

To fix this I changed:

```
<option value="{entity_id}"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></option>
```

To

```
<option **id="src_array[g]"** value="{entity_id}"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></option>
```